# 403 error with a curl request being made over https

Tags: php, nginx, ssl, curl, php-curl

so this is the code i have ... seems to work well over my localhost and production servers but somehow is failing in my clients server....

```
function curl2($url, $urlencoded)
{
    $options = null;
    $headers = false;
   
    $cacert='/home/ooo/public_html/cacert.pem';
    
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');


    session_write_close();

    /* Initialise curl request object */
    $curl=curl_init();
    if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME)=='https') {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert);
    }
    /* Define standard options */    

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);           
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $urlencoded); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh);
    /* Assign runtime parameters as options */
    if (isset($options) && is_array($options)) {
        foreach ($options as $param => $value) {
            curl_setopt($curl, $param, $value);
        }
    }
    if ($headers && is_array($headers)) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }
    /* Execute the request and store responses */
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec($curl),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo($curl),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error($curl)
    );       
    rewind($vbh);
    $res->verbose=stream_get_contents($vbh);
    fclose($vbh);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $res;
}


$vars = array(
    'act'=>$_GET['act']
    );
    $urlencoded = http_build_query($vars);   
    $res=curl2("https://www.example.com/test/receivefeed.php",$urlencoded);
    print_r($res->verbose);
```

the response i get is this

> - Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.108:443...
> - Connected to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (xxx.xxx.xxx.108) port 443 (#0)
> - ALPN: offers h2
> - ALPN: offers http/1.1
> - CAfile: /home/ooo/public_html/cacert.pem
> - CApath: none
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> - ALPN: server accepted h2
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: CN=example.com
> - start date: Apr  6 13:34:23 2023 GMT
> - expire date: Apr  6 13:34:23 2024 GMT
> - subjectAltName: host "www.example.com" matched cert's "www.example.com"
> - issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure
>   Certificate Authority - G2
> - SSL certificate verify ok.
> - Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
> - Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
> - h2h3 [:method: POST]
> - h2h3 [:path: /test/receivefeed.php]
> - h2h3 [:scheme: https]
> - h2h3 [:authority: www.example.com]
> - h2h3 [user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110
>   Safari/537.36]
> - h2h3 [accept: */*]
> - h2h3 [accept-encoding: deflate, gzip]
> - h2h3 [content-length: 5]
> - h2h3 [content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
> - Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x2cefdd0)
>
> > POST /test/receivefeed.php HTTP/2 Host: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> > like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 accept: */*
> > accept-encoding: deflate, gzip content-length: 5 content-type:
> > application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> - We are completely uploaded and fine
> - old SSL session ID is stale, removing
> - Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)! < HTTP/2 403  < server: nginx < date: Mon, 29 May 2023 12:48:39 GMT <

> content-type: text/html < x-sucuri-id: 11008 < x-xss-protection: 1;

> mode=block < x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN < x-content-type-options:

> nosniff < content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; <

> x-sucuri-block: FBP007

> - The requested URL returned error: 403

The host is godaddy

There are two different ip involved so the request is going from a sub domain(yyy.xxx.com) to parent domain(xxx.com) account . But both have different ip addresses and hosting accounts.

subdomain file: sendfeed.php
parent domain file: receivefeed.php

when the post variable is received by receivefeed.php it should send me an email.

i have tried accessing the subdomain file and parent domain file with https and https : When using only http the godaddy server redirects the request from port 80 to port 443 and converts the POST to GET .
Cant understand what i seem to be doing wrong and why am i getting the 403 error when i send the request by https.

i get code 200 if i send the request using http. but for some reason the post variables are not received by the parent domain file.

Comment: ```the response i get is this``` - but what does your client get when he runs it on his server that isn't working?

Comment: if it's an old version of libcurl, might be a http/2 bug, it hasn't always been completely stable. if you do ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);``` does it make a difference? (also try CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1)